# tee: /OR_595.txt: Permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions

I'm trying to append the address information to a file.  I am getting an error message of

> tee: /OR_595.txt: Permission denied

I'm using the following code to create the file.

```
cstates=($(awk -v FS=^ '{print $5}' "$1"))

for i in "${cstates[@]}"
do

    :

if [[ ! -f "./$2/$i/${i}_595.txt" ]]; then

    echo "Making ${i}_595.txt File"
    touch "./$2/$i/${i}_595.txt"
    chmod a+x "./$2/$i/${i}_595.txt"
    else echo "File ${i}_595.txt already exists"


fi
done
```

This code is writing to the file.

```
file_name="$1"

while IFS=^ read -r company_name address1 address2 city state zip phone
do

printf "Company Name: %s\nCompany Address: %s%s, %s, %s, %s\nCompany Phone Number: %s\n\n" \
      "${company_name}" "${address1}" "${address2}" "${city}" "${state}" "${zip}" "${phone}" | tee -a "${outputdir}/${state}_595.txt" > /dev/null

done < $file_name
```

I've checked the permissions on the each of the folders, subfolders and the file

```
drwxrwxr-x 56 jh78454 jh78454 4096 Feb 19 14:58 States
drwxrwxr-x 2 jh78454 jh78454 4096 Feb 19 15:14 WA
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jh78454 jh78454 0 Feb 19 15:14 WA_595.txt
```

I've looked at the permissions via WinSCP for several of the folders and files and they are all the same.  Not sure why I'm getting permission denied error.

Comment: Where is `${outputdir}` defined?

Comment: I search all of your code, but I can't find where you use `tee`.

Comment: Also edit question to tell us what operating system, and file-system you are using.

Comment: Inspect your error message. "outputdir" is undefined or empty. Consequently, it is trying to write to a file in the root directory, for Oregon. "/OR_595.txt" is a bit of a give-away.

Comment: Why are you using `tee` but discarding part of its output? That makes no sense - use `printf "..." >> "${outputdir}/${state}_595.txt"` instead.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Seems to be a good catch of an undefined variable. One could try to execute their scripts with `sh -eu` to detect places where an undefined variable is used (without human attention needed to read the script carefully).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Not sure why I'm getting permission denied error.

Apparently `${outputdir}` expands to an empty string (the variable is not defined or empty) and `${state}` expands to `OR`. This way `${outputdir}/${state}_595.txt` expands to `/OR_595.txt`.

`/OR_595.txt` points to a file named `OR_595.txt` in the root directory `/`. This file probably doesn't exist. It's normal a regular user cannot create "random" files in `/`.

Define `outputdir` so `${outputdir}/${state}_595.txt` points to a file you can write to. You're using `tee -a` so *maybe* the design is the file already exists. I *guess* the first snippet is supposed to create the file. It uses `./$2/$i/`, so you need to set `outputdir` in the second snippet accordingly.

Comment: Correct,  the ${outputdir} should have been $2 and it was missing a subfolder.

$2/$5/${state}_595.txt is correct instead of ${outputdir}/${state}_595.txt

I keep looking at the code and completely missed it.

Comment: Your use of tee in `| tee -a "${outputdir}/${state}_595.txt" > /dev/null` is not necessary. It appends a copy of the output to the file, and then discards the output. Shell appends to files with the >> operator. That whole pipeline extension could be written `>> "${outputdir}/${state}_595.txt"`. In fact, that whole output could be moved outside the while block, like `done < "$file_name"  >> "${outputdir}/${state}_595.txt"`. That avoids the output being opened and closed for each line added.